# ¿Cómo me conecto a un server de BD Oracle clonado?

Tags: oracle

Tengo el siguiente escenario:

Tengo un servidor de Base de Datos Oracle al cual puedo acceder normalmente desde los clientes utilizando el tnsname, este servidor es una maquina virtual. Para tener otro server de pruebas decidi clonar ese servidor, pero ahora no me permite acceder al servidor clonado, cuando intento acceder desde sql developer me aparece el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente en mi TNSname del cliente tengo agregado una nueva conexión con la IP del nuevo server (el clon), alguien sabe a que podría deberse este problema?.

Gracias de antemano y saludos cordiales a todos.

Comment: has probado a hacer ping a la maquina virtual? si no te hace ping puede que tengas que deshabilitad el firewall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno por falta de experiencia en el tema es que se me presento el problema, ya que tenia dos inconvenientes:

- EL Listener estaba configurado con alias de la maquina original
- El firewal (no se como) de la maquina clon apareció activo y tuve que desactivarlo.

Saludos cordiales a todos.